# How to replace a spark dataframe row with another spark dataframe's row using java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark

I have 2 data frames

df1

```
+--------------------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 ID |B  |C                   |            D       |
+--------------------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|                   1|1.0|                 1.0|                 1.0|
|                   2|2.0|                 2.0|                 2.0|
|                   3|3.0|                 3.0|                 3.0|
|                   4|4.0|                 4.0|                 4.0|
+--------------------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

df2

```
+--------------------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 ID |B  |C                   |            D       |
+--------------------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|                   1|100|                 1.0|                 100|
+--------------------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

If ID in df2 matches an ID in df1, I want to replace the row in df1 with the updated values in df2. So the new df1 looks like:

df1

```
+--------------------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 ID |B  |C                   |            D       |
+--------------------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|                   1|100|                 1.0|                 100|
|                   2|2.0|                 2.0|                 2.0|
|                   3|3.0|                 3.0|                 3.0|
|                   4|4.0|                 4.0|                 4.0|
+--------------------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I've been trying to figure this out with union and join and just not having any luck yet.  I first created a new dataframe based on filtering for the ID of df1 and that works and I called that dataframe matchedDF that looks like:

matchedDF (dataframe based on finding a match of ID 1 in df1)

```
+--------------------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 ID |B  |C                   |            D       |
+--------------------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|                   1|1.0|                 1.0|                 1.0|
+--------------------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

But I don't know if I just want to delete the original ID 1 in df1 and add the new matchedDF or do I somehow want to update the original ID 1 with the matchedDf?  Or am I approaching this all wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stay computationally efficient, it's always a good idea to avoid joins/shuffles where possible.

This looks like a case where it is possible to avoid joining, have a look at the following code (it is in Scala, but the principles remain the same):

```scala
// Constructing the 2 dfs
val df = Seq(
  (1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
  (2, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0),
  (3, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0),
  (4, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0)
).toDF("ID", "B", "C", "D")

val df2 = Seq(
  (1, 100, 1.0, 100),
  (2, 100, 1.0, 100)
).toDF("ID", "B", "C", "D")

// Collecting the IDs to be updated into a single Array
// IMPORTANT: we make the assumption that this array is not large (in your
// example there is only 1 row here, so the array only has 1 element which is
// totally fine)
val newIds = df2.select("ID").collect.map(_.getInt(0))

// Removing the original rows with the unwanted IDs and unioning the result with
// the new rows
val output = df
  .filter(not(col("ID").isin(newIds: _*)))
  .union(df2)

scala> output.show
+---+-----+---+-----+                                                           
| ID|    B|  C|    D|
+---+-----+---+-----+
|  3|  3.0|3.0|  3.0|
|  4|  4.0|4.0|  4.0|
|  1|100.0|1.0|100.0|
|  2|100.0|1.0|100.0|
+---+-----+---+-----+
```

So basically, if we can make the assumption that `df2` (with the new values) is small like in your example, you can do something like the following:

- `collect` the `ID` values into a single (undistributed) `Array`. From your example it seems like this is OK. If the amount of new rows is really large this might not be the best approach
- `filter` the original `df` using the `isin` method of a column and negating using `not` (basically removing the rows with the new IDs)
- `union` the filtered `df` and `df2`, resulting in the rows being updated WITHOUT any expensive operation like a shuffle

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response.  I'll try this out today and report back.

Comment: So it turned out that converting that to Java was not as easy as I thought :)  I couldn't find any solution to negate the "isin" using java.  It obviously doesn't use "not", but also "!" doesn't work either. I think what you have would work if I could convert it to Java okay, but I couldn't figure it out.  What I ended up doing to solve my particular issue was to get the dataframe that matches the ID I'm looking for and then "finalDf= df.except(matchedDf).union(df2);" This is code for a PUT Rest call.  The ID defaults to null, but if  you specify an ID, then it replaces the record for that ID.

Comment: Ahhhh happy to hear you found what you need!